# Measuring Variance of 2D Data Points

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I have a list of weighted data points on a 2D plane in the form $(x, y)$.  I believe the mean can calculated as $\left(\frac{\sum{x_i\times w_i}}{\sum w_i}, \frac{\sum{y_i\times w_i}}{\sum w_i}\right)$.

What is the best way to calculate a single value which will accurately describe the spread of the data points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have computed the weighted mean $$\mathbf{\bar x}_* = \sum w_i\mathbf{x}_i$$ (assume $\sum w_i = 1$ for ease of notation). Then why not use weighted variance 
$$\sum w_i|\mathbf{x}_i -\mathbf{\bar x}_*|^2$$
or, for an unbiased version, use the unbiased weighted variance
$$\frac{1}{1-\sum w_i^2}\sum w_i|\mathbf{x}_i -\mathbf{\bar x}_*|^2$$

Here, $|\cdot|$ denotes the ordinary Euclidean norm $|\mathbf u| = \sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2}$, so $|\mathbf{ u }|^2 = u_1^2+u_2^2$.

Comment: You probably also need to take into account that the variance in 2D is a covariance matrix, rather than a scalar?

Answer (score 0):

This expands on the comment by Dr_Zaszuś:

Generally, $$V(X + Y) = V(X) + V(Y) + \text{Cov}(X, Y) + \text{Cov}(Y, X)$$

However, according to Definition 6.10 in *[Mathematics for Machine Learning](https://mml-book.github.io/)*, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then you can define the variance, denoted $V$, of $X$ and $Y$ as,

$$V(X + Y) = V(X) + V(Y)$$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1948320)

Comment: Would you please elaborate?